# flow_from_directory seems to find no images but correctly recognized classes

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory, tf.keras

i have impelmented the code below for loading images from my directory

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
DATA_TRAIN_PATH='/content/drive/MyDrive/persiandataset/PersianDataset/train'
DATA_VALIDATION_PATH ='/content/drive/MyDrive/persiandataset/PersianDataset/validation'
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

IMG_WIDTH =32
IMG_HEIGHT =32
EPOCHS_VGG=60
BATCH_SIZE_VGG=500

train_generator  = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        DATA_TRAIN_PATH,
        target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_VGG,
        subset = "training",
        class_mode='categorical')

test_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        DATA_VALIDATION_PATH,
        target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_VGG,
        subset = "validation",
        class_mode='categorical')
```

the result shows :
Found 37109 images belonging to 32 classes.

**Found 0 images belonging to 32 classes.**

but I have correctly defined subdirectories for my validation data, and there is no difference between defining train directory and validation directory but it does not recognized my images in the validation folder.
how can I fix this issue?
I also attached the image of my folder [subdirectory for images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpknD.png)

my validation directory contains 32 classes with 27 images in each subdirectory.and all the validation data is equal to 864.

Comment: What is the extension of images?

Comment: @Kaveh it's ".tif"

Answer (score 2):

Setting `subset="training"` or `subset="validation"` might be throwing things off, since you didn't set `validation_split` in the `ImageDataGenerator()` class. Can you try without this argument set like this:

```py
test_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        DATA_VALIDATION_PATH,
        target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_VGG,
        class_mode='categorical')
```